# Is it possible to determine if a Cypher MERGE results in a create or a match?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Consider the Neo4J 2.0 Cypher query

```
MERGE (u:User {id_str:"123"}) 
  ON CREATE SET
    u.name="Bob",
  ON MATCH SET
    u.phone_num="555-4152"
RETURN u
```

It's a silly query - don't worry about the intent here. The question is, how do I understand whether this query created or simply found a node?

**UPDATE**

Perhaps I should further motivate why I want this behavior. Here's why: If the node already exists, then don't have to go to a remote server (Twitter API in my case) and download all of the user's metadata. It would be nice if the ON CREATE could somehow link back out to a callback to pull down this data. It seems unlikely that this behavior is achievable in Cypher. So probably what I'll want to do is do a match, and if the get comes back NULL, then I'll call out to the Twitter API, get the metadata and do a create.

Comment: You could set a dummy property, check it, and the delete it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that's contrary to the intention of `MERGE`. You would use it to describe what you want the graph to look like after your query has executed, not to find out what it looks like before–read and write operations are supposed to be kept strictly apart in Cypher. That said, you can set a dummy property like @LameCoder mentioned:

```
MERGE (u:User {id_str:"123"}) 
  ON CREATE SET u.onCreate = true
WITH u, exists(u.onCreate) as onCreate
REMOVE u.onCreate
RETURN u, onCreate
```

will return `(u), true` if created, `(u), false` if not, and leave no side effects. Or you can maintain timestamps, perhaps one for node creation and one for when the node was last modified–I think that's an example from the documentation. This

```
MERGE (u:User {id_str:"123"}) 
  ON CREATE SET u.created = timestamp()
  ON MATCH SET u.lastModified = timestamp()
RETURN u, has(u.lastModified) as onMerge
```

would be similar to the query above.

Comment: Answer accepted, though look at my update to the question for more info.

Comment: Actually... look at this related question now since I've had a little more time to think: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20354408/348056

Comment: Thanks for posting separate question rather than changing this one or following up in comments, I don't know if I can be helpful but I'll try when I get a chance.

Answer (score 4):

In Neo4j console, you may see that the query returns both *summary* and *response*. In Python, I check the `result.summary().counters.nodes_created != 0`.

*Example*: create a connected node with creation timestamp

```
query = """
    match (root:User {username:$root})
    merge (root) -[:HAS_ROOM]-> (r:Room {id:$rid})
        on create set r.timestamp = timestamp()
    return r"""
result = session.run(query, root=user, rid=role)
count = result.summary().counters.nodes_created 
record = result.single()   # Node data
if count > 0: print(f"Node {record['rp']} created")
else: print(f"Using an existing node {record['rp']}")
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I added an example. See https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/results.html#neo4j.SummaryCounters

Comment: If a query is just creating one node and we have access to the driver's result object, I think this is the better approach as it doesn't dirty the query with extra logic.