# Neo4j merge return something only if it was created

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Neo4j's merge will create new node if it doesn't exist. And it has `ON CREATE` and `ON MATCH` as two distinctions. However, is there a way to return different information if the node was created as to if the node was matched?

```
MERGE (charlie { name:'Charlie Sheen' })
ON CREATE SET charlie.name = 'Charlie'
RETURN charlie
```

Something like: `ON CREATE RETURN 1, ON MERGE RETURN 0`

Comment: Check the answer to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274979/is-it-possible-to-determine-if-a-cypher-merge-results-in-a-create-or-a-match

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a [relevant example on the merge page of the documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html#_use_on_create_and_on_match):

```
MERGE (keanu:Person { name:'Keanu Reeves' })
ON CREATE SET keanu.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET keanu.lastSeen = timestamp()
RETURN keanu.name, has(keanu.lastSeen);
```

Basically this stores your 0 or 1 flag in the existence or absence of the "lastSeen" attribute.

Your query has this oddity that you're matching on "Charlie Sheen" but then modifying the value you matched (`name`) to be "Charlie".   That's odd -- it means that because you're modifying it each time, even if you add an `ON MATCH` clause, it will never fire.  You'll create it new each time, then modify it, guaranteeing it will be created new the next time you run that query.   I would guess that it's a bad idea to modify the terms of your match later in the query, unless it's a special circumstance.

Comment: The cypher in my question is just a random example. I just wrote it down for this question only. I want to implement this on status update `likes`. Basically I want to ensure that a post is not liked by a user twice and that the query gives `has(...)` information. Your answer solves my issue. Thanks.